# A way to generate devise views that already include bootstrap CSS styling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This devise generator saves a mountain of work by making all the views necessary for authentication:

```sh
rails g devise:views
```

Can the views above be generated but with bootstrap styling already included? E.g. perhaps similar to how `rails new` has the `css=bootstrap` option.

Note: I realise that styling is necessarily opinionated, however, it wouldn't be a bad thing since it would be a time-saver.

Comment: maybe with some "devise bootstrap" gem. `devise` itself comes with one set of views.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [rails templates](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html).

An example with bootstrap and devise: https://github.com/lewagon/rails-templates

*Note*: It might be specific to the Le Wagon setup but I believe you can use the same approach to tailor it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This gem adds bootstrap views:

https://github.com/kroger/devise-bootstrap5

Just add these two gems to your gemfile and you're basically done.

```
...
gem "devise-i18n"
gem "devise-bootstrap5"
...
```

Comment: this link is a 404